# Can't generate changelog with conventional-changelog

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, changelog

I'm trying to set up a new workflow for a new project I'm working at. I really would like to use conventional-changelog, but for the moment is being impossible to me to make it work.

First of all, I can't even make the cli tool working. I did installed globally, but each time I'm trying to run:
`conventional-changelog --help` on the shell, it said: `conventional-changelog: command not found`, but if I make `npm ls -g -depth=0` I can see conventional-changelog@0.0.17 package listed.

Another issue I'm having is that I can't create the changelog.

I have already some commits (indeed only one) on the angular format. It's like this:

`feat(): onUrlChange event (popstate/hashchange/polling)`

(this is an example copied from the docs, for debugging)

I also have a CHANGELOG.md empty file on the root and I have created a test.js with the following:

```
var conventionalChangelog = require('conventional-changelog');

conventionalChangelog({
  preset: 'angular'
})
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

Whenever run node test I get :

```
conventionalChangelog().pipe(process.stdout);
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antonio/Projects/cabesa/test.js:45:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Any suggestion to put me on the right spot ?

My final goal will be to create some gulp tasks that manage all process automatically: deploying, documentation, testing, etc... but I'm stuck here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that their documentation only reflects the state of the code currently in the master branch. The last release was in April, when [the exported function did not return anything](https://github.com/ajoslin/conventional-changelog/blob/3cae05244e48af9cf4abbef3114060db585a574c/index.js#L45) (hence the `undefined` error you're seeing). You may try installing from the master branch (`npm install https://github.com/ajoslin/conventional-changelog/tarball/master`), or use the documentation that was available at the time of the last release ([v0.0.17](https://github.com/ajoslin/conventional-changelog/blob/3cae05244e48af9cf4abbef3114060db585a574c/README.md) as of this writing).

Comment: Great ! That was what I was missing. I think they should reflect this on their docs. Thanks a lot !